# The description of Al Dabbah, the beast from the earth with the ring of Solomon staff of Moses?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

Is the hadiths pertaining to the description and actions of the beast of the earth during the end times "Al Dabbah" authentic? From the prophet Muhamamd (saw) and the companions? Or are they Israreliyat narrations from the people of the book.

Tafsir ibn Kathir, Abu Dawood Al-Tayalisi in his Musnad, Imam Ahmad, Jami at Tirmidhi etc report the following narrations from the prophet Muhammad (saw) and some of the companions. (see links below) Attributed to the Prophet from Abu Hurayah.. the beast with staff of Moses and ring of Solomon adorning face of believers and striking non believers. And the  description of the beast with the eyes of pigs, ears of elephant and neck of ostrich etc from ibn Az Zubayr.

Are these marfo narrations authentic from Prophet Muhammad and how did the companions come to know of the description of the beast are these mawqoof Israreliyat narrations or attributetd to the Prophet Muhammad are they authentic?

http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=2222

http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=89092

https://sunnah.com/urn/642160

Answer (score 1):

Ustadth Nouman Ali Khan:
Waitha waqaAAa alqawlu AAalayhim – When the word is set on them, waqaAAa except one place in Surat Nisa used in negative sense in the Quran. akhrajna lahum dabbatan mina alardi – We will take out for them a great creature (beast) from the land. tukallimuhum – that’s gonna talk to them.  anna alnnasa kanoo biayatina la yooqinoona  - that this people they were the one who did not have conviction in our ayat, in our miraculous signs  (Surat An-Naml ayat 82)

Shaykh Dr. Yasir Kadhi:
Once the command has been given, which means once the Judgement is khalas that’s it, too late now, once the motion has been set in, then that’s it end is coming, the end is near. We shall bring out for them a Beast from this earth. The beast will speak to them and it will say. People would not believe in our signs, it’s too late now, we told you to believe, you didn’t.

And Prophet sallallahu alayhi wassalam said, hadith in Sahih Muslim, narrated on the authority of Abu Huraira (r.a.): "When three things appear faith will not benefit one who has not previously believed or has derived no good from his faith: The Rising of the Sun in its place of setting, the Dajjal, and the beast of the Earth" (Sahih Muslim 158, Book 1, Hadith 305, In-book reference)

And this is ahadith that has caused a little bit of commentary controversy because, Dajjal? Can you not accept after the Dajjal comes? That’s a bit of controversy. But the point is these two explicitly mention: The rising of the sun from the west and the Dabbat ul ard, when these two happen the there is no repentance and if a person has not accepted iman, end of story.
Now what is this Beast? And what are the details?  The Quran has only this one verse, the hadith, there is a lot of apocryphal hadith, hadith that are found in the very obscure works, that are not mainstream (not in a 6 books). As for the famous 6 books of hadith the only authentic ahadith mention Dabba and that’s it, no adjective, no description, it just mentions the beast of the earth.
There is a hadith in Tirmidhi, that Tirmidhi himself says is a weak, it is a weak hadith without any ikhtilaf, you look it up the isnad is obvious, clearly it is weak, but is in Tirmidhi. The hadith says that the beast shall have with it the staff of Musa (alayhi salam) and the ring of Sulaiman (alayhi salam), so it says that this beast in one hand will carry the staff and in the other hand a ring. However, this seems to be coming from Judaeo-Christian sources.

In Musnad Imam Ahmad, there is a hadith that has an unknown chain, once again it’s not authentic. In which it says that the beast will mark people with a symbol, the beast will stamp, and stamp people with iman and kufr, who’s a muslim who’s a kaffir. It is problematic in terms of its content, it says beast will stamp people with mu’min and kaffir, but when is the beast coming? There are no mu’mins left in earth (Note from author: before repentance door is closed the wind will come from the Yaman like a silk and will take the souls of mu’min, so, at last two old people will stay saying “I remember that my grand grand father was saying La ilaha illallah, but I don’t know what it means”, refer to the lectures of Yasir Qadhi if you want to check). So even from a content wise it doesn’t make any sense. By the time the beast comes, the Quran, where is it? The Kalima, where is it? Allah Allah has not been mentioned on Earth, we already talked about that, that generation will come where there is not actual Quran left. So the beast will come at a time, literally it’s the last day on existence, the beast will come out and that’s is too late obviously, for anybody to accept, now

Allah knows best

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE. Please mark your quotes as such to cleraly distinguish them from your own words!